# How can I access to a website which has md5 using python?

Tags: javascript, python, md5

I'm using python to access to my school's website to get some data(first step is to log in).however the website encrypt the password before post to the server,just like this:

1. fill password in the form(which named 'pw')
2. encrypt for the first time:pw = md5(pw)
3. encrypt for the second time:pw = md5(pw+sharedValue)(the sharedValue is different every time when open the website)
4. post the pw which has been encrypted twice,and turn to the welcome page
   So,how can I access to this website using python?

---

I have tried to open the website to get the sharedValue and get the encrypted-twice-password in python and then post those data to the server, however it didn't return anything.

Comment: Take a look at requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to access the webpage, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse it to find the sharedValue (assuming it's stored in a hidden form field). Calculate the md5 with the built in hashlib module. Send the password (and presumably username) to the login page with requests, store the cookie it returns and use it on all future page interactions, including accessing the welcome page.

Comment: I have done everything but store the cookie.I will have a try. Thank you!